# How can I give permissions of files to multiple groups?

Tags: linux, permissions

I got an exercise to create a directory called Projekte and I'm supposed to give the groups Auftrag and Support the permissions r and w but the others only r

I just realised that this is impossible. What can I do?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Would creating a new group to which you add all affected users be an option? This would force you to have to manage individuals in multiple groups though, rather than groups of individuals...

Comment: I don't know whether our teacher meant this but that is a great idea. I could possibly create secondary groups to merge the users of both groups into one helper group. The problem would be that I have more exercise like that and this would be very unclear

Comment: That would be the "classic" way of doing it, but someone who knows about ACLs (or some other relevant mechanic) may have a better answer.

Comment: If you got this as an exercise, then it's very likely not impossible. Don't assume something is impossible because you don't know how :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not be able to do this by creating a new group, as you need some users to have read and some to have read/write. That is unless you need the users from `Auftrag` and `Support` to have read/write and *everyone* else to have read permissions, in which case you could create a group which contains all the users from `Auftrag` and `Support`, and set group write and world read.

Alternatively, and assuming your filessytem supports them, you could use extended ACLs:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

For example:

```
# setfacl -m "g:Auftrag:rw" /file/path

# setfacl -m "g:Support:rw" /file/path
```

Comment: This flavor of ACLs was proposed for a standard in 1993 but withdrawn in 1997. it is no longer in use with modern filesystems.

Comment: I'm not sure what schily is talking about, these commands certainly do work in a quick test I just did, using `btrfs`

Comment: An answer that is of very limited use does not really help and at lest should be marked as an answer that might not help.

Comment: @schily An answer that answers the question is of great use. I'm also going to repeat the ask of "what are you talking about?". Please back up your claims if you're going to make them.

Comment: I mentioned that the given answer does not answer the question as it is based on a proposal that is outdated since more than 20 years.

Comment: Why don't you read the pointer you mentioned first? If you don't understand this, you should give a useful question that could allow to help you.

Comment: @rustyshackleford There are a few things about this answer that should be adjusted/noted. The question is asking about a directory, thus it needs the e`x`ecute bit as well. Also with filesystem ACLs, even if the group has all perms stripped prior to the `setfacl`, the `setfacl` will add some back. Thus it's important to make sure the group of the file is either one of the groups that should have access, or is a group nobody is in (or something like `root`).

Comment: As much as I enjoy a good debate. He (schily) has no intention of backing up his claim, or providing any sort of proof. So lets just let him spew whatever he wants to spew.

Comment: Well, could you ask and explain what you don't understand or what intention do you have? So please either inform yourself about ACLs or send a useful question that explains what you don't understand. But please stop this useless ping-ping game.

Comment: @schily What I think people are hoping is that you could at least back up your claim. Do you have a link to support your claims about 1993 and 1997? Are you in the context of Linux, or another OS? All I'm seeing out there are modern references to this method. Not only that, I'm seeing it as the only apparent / most visible method. Does it not work in all major Linux distributions, is that a concern?

Comment: @groovenectar If you did read the related standard draft, you would know that the draft has been withdrawn, since it is in the text. If you have some knowledge on OS history, you could know that Solaris introduced this type of ACLs around 1993 and that the draft in question describes the old implementation on Solaris. If you know not only Linux, you know that all modern filesystems:  what Apple uses now, what IBM uses now and ZFS implement NFSv4 ACLs that have been modelled to be bitwise identical to NTFS ACLs. Linux started to support the old ACLs in 2001 and does not yet support new ones.

Comment: @schily I didn't read it, because I do not know where to find it. That is the whole point, we were not sure where you are getting your information.

Comment: @groovenectar since there is google & co, it is easy to retrieve the documents if you like. If you like to get real information it may be a bad idea to only look at people that know nothing besides Linux in special if their claims are not backed up by serious information.

Comment: @schily Of course I tried Google. I'm not familiar with your claims, so that's why we were hoping you would back them with a copy/paste of a URL. This is certainly a frustrating SO thread.

Comment: @groovenectar It is a bad practice to attack people like you did and you should not expect help if you attack people instead of kindly asking... BTW: do not use majestatis pluralis, this sounds not serious. Here http://simson.net/ref/1997/ is the PDF for download.

Comment: @groovenectar you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

I have to assume that the goal includes the execute bit as well in order to change into the directory.

Become the root user.

```
sudo -i
```

Create the directory. (The root user is the owner and group owner.)

```
mkdir Projekte
```

Define the permissions. Let's make it accessible only to root to highlight the affect of the ACLs.

```
chmod 0700
```

Now augment standard permissions with ACLs.

```
setfacl -d -m g:Auftrag:7 Projekte
setfacl -m g:Auftrag:7 Projekte

setfacl -d -m g:Support:7 Projekte
setfacl -m g:Support:7 Projekte

setfacl -d -m o::5 Projeckte
setfacl -m o::5 Projeckte
```

Above, the `-m` switch is the mask, and the `-d` switch makes the mask the default mask for all new filesystem objects in the directory. Octal values need not be used. The same can be written as follows.

```
setfacl -d -m g:Auftrag:rwx Projekte
setfacl -m g:Auftrag:rwx Projekte

setfacl -d -m g:Support:rwx Projekte
setfacl -m g:Support:rwx Projekte

setfacl -d -m o::r-x Projeckte
setfacl -m o::r-x Projeckte
```

The user, group, and other masks work the same way: `g:groupname:---` or in combination: `u:username:---,g:groupname:---,o::---`, where `o` means others. Not specifying a username or group name applies the mask to current user/group ownership.

Notice how both a mask and a default mask were applied. The mask (without `-d`) applies to the directory itself. The mask (with `-d`) applies to all new filesystem objects in the directory. It's easy to [forget this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131420/using-acl-with-multiple-default-groups).

Comment: See other comment: a proposal to standardize this flavor of ACLs has been withdrawn in 1997.

Comment: Nevertheless it works all day every for decades until today,

Comment: So you either work on a platform with a filesystem that has not been made up to date since 20 years, or you work on a platform where the creators do not care about recent standards. All modern filesystems that have been written after y2000 support the NFSv4/NTFS ACL concept (see Mac OS, AIX, Solaris/ZFS, FreeBSD). Old filesystems however may still use this old ACL concept, but Solaris/SAMFS and FreeBSD did upgrade even some old filesystems to support the current ACL standard.

Comment: The tag is linux.